# Using a single component multiple times in a single parent class in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-component, react-component-unmount

```
class Counter extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        age: 10,
    };
}
handleincrement = () => {
    console.log("hy");
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return { age: prevState.age + 1 };
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleincrement}>
                counter value is {this.state.age}
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

```
function App() {
return (
    <div>
        <Counter />
        <Counter />
    </div>
);
```

}

I have a one component Counter and i am using is 2 time times in App.js class when i click first button it result in increasing state value of only first Counter component and vice verse.
My question is that why these both components behave independentaly from each other?

Comment: because the counter component has its own state. Two Counter Child component means they both have their independent instance as well as states.

Answer (score 1):

Each component has its [**own lifecycle**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

For sharing the same state, what **is recommended**, is [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up):

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.age}</div>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    age: 0
  };

  handleincrement = () => {
    this.setState(prev => ({ age: prev.age + 1 }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleincrement}>Increase</button>
        <Counter age={this.state.age} />
        <Counter age={this.state.age} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For completeness, you can use a global variable too (**not recommended**).

Something like:

```
let age = 10;

class Counter extends React.Component {
  handleincrement = () => {
    age++;
    this.forceUpdate();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleincrement}>counter value is {age}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Counter />
      <Counter />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Q-62789676-LiftStateUp]

Answer (score 0):

It is because both are separate Child Components of Parent class App.
This not a constructor props or something that is within App Class.
You are importing both components so they are just coming individually.